# can i qualify on orientdb vertex/edge class in a gremlin query?

Tags: orientdb, gremlin

orientdb has a seemingly 'non-standard' feature to be able to create specific classes of vertices and edges.

`g.createVertex('class:person')`

but it's unclear to me if/how i can qualify on that class via 'standard' gremlin?

i have seen a reference to a syntax like so:

`g.V('@class','person')...`

[here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35447890/2371903), but then there was mention of this syntax skirting indices.

can anyone shed light on this topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that Gremlin doesn't adopt the Schema feature and not all of the graph databases support schemas, so I don't think that you can manipulate the OrientDB Schema directly with Gremlin.

Anyway, you can use the `createVertexType()` command to create classes inside OrientDB trhought Gremlin.

1. **Connection to ODB database:**

   ```
   g = new OrientGraphNoTx('remote:localhost/GremlinDB')

   ==>orientgraphnotx[remote:localhost/GremlinDB]
   ```
2. **Create the Vertex class `Person` that extends `V`:**

   ```
   g.createVertexType('Person','V')

   ==>Person
   ```

Now, if you look at the Schema in OrientDB Studio, you'll see the new class created:

[image]

**EDITED**

After having added two vertices

[image]

we can find the person with `name = 'John'`.

1. **Using `has()`:**

   ```
   g.V.has('@class','Person').has('name','John')

   ==>v(Person)[#12:0]
   ```
2. **Using `has()` + `T` operator:**

   ```
   g.V.has('@class','Person').has('name',T.eq,'John')

   ==>v(Person)[#12:0]
   ```
3. **Using `contains()`:**

   ```
   g.V.has('@class','Person').filter{it.name.contains('John')}

   ==>v(Person)[#12:0]
   ```
4. **Using `==`:**

   ```
   g.V.has('@class','Person').filter{it.name == 'John'}

   ==>v(Person)[#12:0]
   ```

Hope it helps

Comment: thanks @LucaS, yes, i have already used `createVertexType` to create the subclass of V, but my question is around the idiomatic way to now search on that subclass in a gremlin query (e.g. find me all Persons whose first-name is 'lucas')...

Comment: Hi @tony_k, I missed the query :). I'm editing my answer.

Comment: Hi @tony_k, I posted some methods you can use to retrieve the results you're looking for. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi @tony_k, did you have a chance to try the queries ?

Comment: thanks @LucaS, these queries look good, i will accept your answer. do you have any idea around "@class" and indexes? i.e. does "@class" have an implicit index on it and do these queries use it?

Comment: Hi @tony_k, thanks for voting. At the moment I can't tell you much about the usage of the indexes in OrientDB - gremlin but I'll look for some useful information. In the meanwhile I found some indications in the [Gremlin official docs](http://gremlindocs.spmallette.documentup.com/#indexmapentry) about the  indexes, but I have to test them. Glad to have been helpful.